# Dynamically generation recursive array of data using CDBCriteria

Tags: multidimensional-array, yii

Please how do i dynamically generate array of data in this format.? What i want to achieve is to use this data with my dropdown list as optiongroup data

```
$data=array(
    'one'=>array(
        '1'=>'Satu',
        '2'=>'Dua',
        '3'=>'Tiga',
     ),
    'two'=>array(
        '1'=>'Sidji',
        '2'=>'Loro',
        '3'=>'Telu',
    ),
    'three'=>array(
        '1'=>'Hiji',
        '2'=>'Dua',
        '3'=>'Tilu',
     ),
);
```

Comment: So you want CArrayDataProvider ?

Comment: Please could you show me example how to use  CArrayDataProvider? to have my cdbcriteria return array of data as showed in my question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupField` attribute of [`CHtml::listData()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) to generate an array like that.

```
$data=CHtml::listData($models,'valueAttribute','labelAttribute','groupAttribute');
```

Where `$models` isa an array of the models. You can directly pass this `$data` array to [`CHtml::dropDownList()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail) and yii will automatically generate `optgroup`s for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
CMap::mergeArray(array($first array),$second array,....nth $array);
```

Comment: this seems not a best solutions for me because my data are been generated dynamically

Comment: @spatanx assign the data to an array and then insert in `CMAP::mergeArray($assigned array1, $assigned array2)`

Comment: Ok, i would try it and get back.